# Key Vault returns 401 with access token (MSI PowerShell Function App)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am trying to connect to **Keyvault** with my **Azure Function** using **PowerShell**.
The Managed Service Identity (MSI) has been turned on, and in Keyvault I granted the MSI 'get' and 'list' access policies.
Using the script below I successfully get an access token, but when I make the request to Keyvault I always receive a 401 response.

```
$vaultName = $Env:KeyVaultName
$vaultSecretName = $Env:VaultSecretName

$tokenAuthURI = $Env:MSI_ENDPOINT + "?resource=https://vault.azure.net/&api-version=2017-09-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"Secret"="$env:MSI_SECRET"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

$headers = @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken" }
$queryUrl = "https://$vaultName.vault.azure.net/keys/" +$vaultSecretName + "?api-version=2016-10-01"

$keyResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $queryUrl -Headers $headers
```

Any idea why the token is not sufficient?

Comment: If you want to get secret, you need to use queryUrl `"https://$vaultName.vault.azure.net/secrets/" +$vaultSecretName + "?api-version=2016-10-01"`. In your case, it seems that you try to get  the key. Do you granted the MSI 'get' and 'list' access policies to access  key?

Comment: @TomSun thank you for noticing I wrongly put `keys` in there. Once Sean helped me get passed the 401, the error messages guided me there too :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing the resource URI to https://vault.azure.net (with no trailing slash). The token validation on the server expects the exact same string as it returns in the 401 response's WWW-Authenticate header. In general, Key Vault returns 401 for cases where the token is missing or fails validation (three common cases are the token is expired, has an incorrect resource URI, or was issued by a different tenant than the vault is associated with).

Comment: Thank you Sean, that was indeed the issue. I copied over the code from somewhere, I'll try to find it and make notice of it so others don't run in to this.

Comment: I probably found the same code you did and this ate 2 days of my life.

Comment: Microsoft! Why?? :'(